# Sodomy Sodomy Sodomy Sodomy

Tags: discussion, political-correctness, sensitive-topics

So, if we're going to have a frank discussion about sodomy.  [Let's just say it, not make allusions to it!](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/709/revisions).  And in saying it (with respect to the individual), we should not have it edited out by any moderation.

But, certainly it would be wise to not be a jerk about it. Be sensitive and above all recognize that even the most depraved sinner (myself included) is a child of God!

Comment: Was there something specific that triggered this rant? Particularly during the beta phase I think it's ok to weigh into specific threads and help clean them up to set an exemplary tone for the site to continue with.

Comment: @caleb, HedgeMedge edited out of post where I had mentioned an act of sodomy as an example. 
PeterTurner, If HedgeMedge did not feel that was necessary, then that's perfectly fine with me that it was edited out.

Comment: @jonathon, that's why I didn't edit it back in there.  I just don't want to start a precedent of not being able to speak frankly about homosexuality (or any other forms of deviance from the natural moral law).  It's the kind of violation of political correctness that's been known to get you expelled from school or fired from your govt. job or arrested (in Canada at least) - and it's exactly what we should be fighting against in our culture.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: @The this is meta man, no questions necessary.  I was just pointing out A. That we shouldn't make lame allusions to sodomy and B. that we shouldn't edit out references to sodomy. (Both of which happened, but I think have satisfactorily been taken care of)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was the one who edited the post.  When someone says "the back door..." it comes off as a giggly fourteen-year-old aside.  "hehe... I mentioned a taboo but if anyone deletes it they're admitting they know what I was alluding to, so I can giggle about them, too". This particular aside was not essential to the meaning of the post, and it was already flagged by users, so it was easiest to just edit it out.

I don't *think* that was the original poster's intention at all.  However, a huge part of private beta is making our site look like the sort of site an expert would want to participate on, so that we attract more experts as time goes on.

If you want to say "sodomy" or "anal sex", fine. They are precise and correct.  Anything that sounds like it was said in a high school bathroom is going to make the visiting expert feel like he/she is in a high school bathroom, and not like he/she wants to stay and share expertise.

Comment: +1 for rebuking me. :)

Comment: Thanks for responding to this HedgeMage, and @JonathonByrd I appreciate your attitude!

Comment: Totally agreed, I just want to make sure there's no precedent for not talking frankly about sodomy.  (so I mentioned it a few times in the title of this post to make sure)

Comment: So are we all in agreement then, that if we're going to talk about sodomy we're going to be up front about it?

Comment: @JonathonByrd: If you did that on purpose, that was horrible. If not I'm blushing enough for the both of us.

Comment: Just making sure :)

Comment: I'm not sure "anal sex" is actually precise and all encompassing: see [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25408/what-acts-qualify-as-sodomy-and-why)

Comment: @ThePreacher I offered both "sodomy" and "anal sex" as possible alternatives because the "back door" comment could have been meant in the context referenced as either an example of a group of behaviors (sodomy) or the problem behavior itself (anal sex).

Answer (score 4):

I think this could be said about any sensitive issue stemming from man's depravity. Your suggestion of dealing with these issues sensitively but directly is sound advice.

Comment: Agreed wholeheartedly, the only reason I wrote this meta post with in response to [this](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/708/why-is-sex-in-the-right-circumstances-still-seemingly-a-sin/709#709) being editted by a mod.